# JUnit test for method which throw an exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a method which throws an exception when the given date and times are invalid.

```
try {
    startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endDate, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
     LOGGER.error(ERROR_PARSING_DATE_TIME, e);
     return false;
}
```

in testing i'm trying to verify this exception with invalid data.

```
@Test
public void should_throw_an_exception_if_failed_to_parse_dates() {
    try {
        parseStartAndEndDates("sdf", "ssdf"); // parsing invalid data here
        fail(); //remember this line, else 'may' false positive
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        assertThat(e.getMessage(), is(ERROR_PARSING_DATE_TIME));
    }
}
```

but this always fail. What should be the correct way to test this kind of situation.

Comment: The Exception is not caught in your test, since it is already caught inside the tested method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your test code as following because you are returning `false` if there an `DateTimeParseException` is thrown

```
@Test
public void should_throw_an_exception_if_failed_to_parse_dates() {
    assertThat(parseStartAndEndDates("sdf", "ssdf")).isFalse(); // parsing invalid data here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways:
1) Throw exception inside the first method:

```
 try {
        startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
        endDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(endDate, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
         LOGGER.error(ERROR_PARSING_DATE_TIME, e);
         throw new DateTimeParseException();
    }
```

...

```
@Test(expected = DateTimeParseException.class)
 public void should_throw_an_exception_if_failed_to_parse_dates(){
    parseStartAndEndDates("sdf", "ssdf"); // parsing invalid data here
}
```

2) check false in your test because `parseStartAndEndDates()` returns `false`:

```
@Test
public void should_throw_an_exception_if_failed_to_parse_dates() {
    assertFalse(parseStartAndEndDates("sdf", "ssdf")); // parsing invalid data here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers said, your method does not in fact throw. The message you're testing for is actually passed to a logger. If that is the API you want, and you still want to test that the right message gets emitted, you'll have to mock the logger in your test